# Updating table content using SQLite?

Tags: iphone, database, xcode, sqlite, tableview

Friends, here is my problem: I populate a table in Xcode using SQLite database. Here is what I want - If my table has 20 rows and all of them are populated, how to update the table if new data is saved in my SQLite database? I want the new information to overwrite the old one. How to do that in Xcode, any ideas? Thanks in advance! I am not sure if the info that I provided is enough, so let me know if you want some code or other stuff.

Comment: Means once u modified or added new record in the SQLite table u need to refresh the table view which is in ur viewcontroller right?

Comment: That's right. And if I have 20 rows and 21 records in my SQLite table, I want the 21st record to overwrite the info in my first row, the 22nd record to overwrite the info in my second row and etc.

Comment: Its a lot of code, but you can see it here: http://www.sourcepod.com/xxsact24-18139
I have two controllers - main controller, where I enter the data and save it to my sqlite db, and flip side controller, where I can see my data.

Comment: I didn't get u. U table row count is always 20 ?  ur requirement resembles like that only.

Comment: In my code my cells are not always 20, but lets imagine that they are exactly 20. And if I have 21 records in my db, I want the last record (the 21st) to overwrite my first record which I display in my first cell. I hope you understand what I mean.

Comment: after getting data from sqlite just reload your tableView > [tableView reloadData];

Comment: Nothing changes when I reload my table. :(

Answer (score 0):

The key to what you're doing is in the routine you furnish for your table: cellForRowAtIndexPath.  Basically, you can write that routine to furnish whatever data you want it to furnish.  Once you know that your data has been updated, you can cause the entire table to refresh with a call to reloadData.

Comment: The problem is that I really don't know what to do. Can you give me an example based on my code or some guidance?

Comment: In your code you should have a method called cellForRowAtIndexPath.  In this method you should be doing two things: 1) providing a Cell object that the table view can display (you either allocate a new one, or recycle an old one - there's lots of sample code for this) and 2) you stuff in the values for this cell based on the index path. So if your method cellForRowAtIndexPath gets called for row 1, you figure out what sqlite record should be equivalent for displayed row 1 (i.e. row 1 or row 21), and you stuff those values in the cell you provide, and return the cell to iOS